# Unable to connect with node.js using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, codeigniter

I am building a voting system using codeigniter framework. There is a page in which I am showing a list of 10 people with there total vote and I wanted to make these voting count in realtime e.g voting count should change when user votes.

[image: Voting page]

Now to make all the finalist total votes real time, I am using node.js but unfortunately the program is not getting the total count.

```
var express    = require("express");
var mysql      = require('mysql');

var connection      =    mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'voting_sys',
});

var app = express();

connection.connect(function(err){
if(!err) {
    console.log("Database is connected ... nn");    
} else {
    console.log("Error connecting database ... nn");    
}
});

app.get("/",function(req,res){
connection.query("SELECT count('*') as votes from voting where finalist_id_fk=1", function(err, rows, fields) {
connection.end();
  if (!err)
    console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
  else
    console.log('Error while performing Query.');
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

When I run this file it only show database is connection where as I want total votes

[image]
Please help me. How can I achieve it and how can I run this node.js file.

Comment: How are you attempting top connect with the node server??

Comment: throught node.js command like node server.js

Comment: I dont follow - you are starting a webserver in node, listening on port 3000. How are you attempting to connect your php webpage to the node server? You mention realtime so i presume websockets, but dont see any websocket related code

Comment: How do I do that ? I am a newbie, don't know about this.

Comment: You should make AJAX request to url 'http://localhost:3000/' and you will see total votes. It's will be works only on local machine

Comment: Thats a really broad subject. I suggest you google "nodejs websockets" or just stick with codeignitor and use ajax polling instead

Comment: yes I can do that with jquery ajax function but i want to make it realtime.

Comment: @mishanon you mean checking for change after every 5 sec. wouldn't it be harmful for server ?

Comment: @Umerm yes it is harmful for server, but we have only 2 options: 1) use this code 2) Learn websocket and using it